# Find longest non-decreasing sequence

Tags: algorithm

Given the following question,

Given an array of integers A of length n, find the longest sequence {i_1, ..., i_k} such that i_j < i_(j+1) and A[i_j] <= A[i_(j+1)] for any j in [1, k-1].

Here is my solution, is this correct?

```
max_start = 0; // store the final result
max_end   = 0;
try_start = 0; // store the initial result
try_end   = 0;

FOR i=0; i<(A.length-1); i++ DO
  if A[i] <= A[i+1]
     try_end = i+1; // satisfy the condition so move the ending point
  else              // now the condition is broken
     if (try_end - try_start) > (max_end - max_start) // keep it if it is the maximum
        max_end   = try_end;
        max_start = try_start;
     endif
     try_start = i+1; // reset the search
     try_end   = i+1;
  endif
ENDFOR

// Checking the boundary conditions based on comments by Jason
if (try_end - try_start) > (max_end - max_start) 
   max_end   = try_end;
   max_start = try_start;
endif
```

Somehow, I don't think this is a correct solution but I cannot find a counter-example that disapprove this solution.

anyone can help?

Thank you

Comment: It looks pretty good to me. Can you give some idea of why you think it's incorrect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see any backtracking in your algorithm, and it seems to be suited for contiguous blocks of non-decreasing numbers.  If I understand correctly, for the following input:

```
1 2 3 4 10 5 6 7
```

your algorithm would return `1 2 3 4 10` instead of `1 2 3 4 5 6 7`.

Try to find a solution using [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming).

Comment: I think this is what I am looking for. As you mentioned, the original question doesn't emphasize that sequence should be continous. -thx

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the case where the condition is not broken at its last iteration:

```
1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10
```

You'll never promote `try_start` and `try_end` to `max_start` and `max_end` unless your condition is broken. You need to perform the same check at the end of the loop.

Comment: I think it's a same comment, but for a list of length 1, this don't run through the loop so you get 0 and 0 for start and end

Comment: I had made a correction for my solution based on your suggestion. However, my concern is that my solution is fundamentally wrong given the original question because the provided solution from the book uses a quite complicated DP to solve it. I think I miss some key information from the question. -thx

Answer (score 1):

Well, it looks like you're finding the start and the end of the sequence, which may be correct but it wasn't what was asked.  I'd start by reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence - I believe this is the question that was asked and it's a fairly well-known problem.  In general cannot be solved in linear time, and will also require some form of dynamic programming.  (There's an easier n^2 variant of the algorithm on Wikipedia as well - just do a linear sweep instead of the binary search.)

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

template<class RandIter>
class CompM {
    const RandIter X;
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<RandIter>::value_type value_type;
    struct elem {
        value_type c; // char type
        explicit elem(value_type c) : c(c) {}
    };
public:
    elem operator()(value_type   c) const { return elem(c); }
    bool operator()(int  a, int  b) const { return X[a]  < X[b];  } // for is_sorted
    bool operator()(int  a, elem b) const { return X[a]  <   b.c; } // for find
    bool operator()(elem a, int  b) const { return   a.c < X[b];  } // for find
    explicit CompM(const RandIter X) : X(X) {}
};

template<class RandContainer, class Key, class Compare>
int upper(const RandContainer& a, int n, const Key& k, const Compare& comp) {
    return std::upper_bound(a.begin(), a.begin() + n, k, comp) - a.begin();
}

template<class RandIter>
std::pair<int,int> lis2(RandIter X, std::vector<int>& P)
{
    int n = P.size(); assert(n > 0);
    std::vector<int> M(n);
    CompM<RandIter> comp(X);
    int L = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        int j = upper(M, L, comp(X[i]), comp);
        P[i] = (j > 0) ? M[j-1] : -1;
        if (j == L) L++;
        M[j] = i;
    }
    return std::pair<int,int>(L, M[L-1]);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s string\n", argv[0]);
        return 3;
    }
    const char* X = argv[1];
    int n = strlen(X);
    if (n == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "param string must not empty\n");
        return 3;
    }
    std::vector<int> P(n), S(n), F(n);
    std::pair<int,int> lt = lis2(X, P); // L and tail
    int L = lt.first;
    printf("Longest_increasing_subsequence:L=%d\n", L);
    for (int i = lt.second; i >= 0; --i) {
        if (!F[i]) {
            int j, k = 0;
            for (j = i; j != -1; j = P[j], ++k) {
                S[k] = j;
                F[j] = 1;
            }
            std::reverse(S.begin(), S.begin()+k);
            for (j = 0; j < k; ++j)
                printf("%c", X[S[j]]);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please explain your code rather than just posting it just the way it this.